# Communication between multiple view-models using MVVM & Prism 4.0

Tags: mvvm, prism-4, wpf-4.0

I am trying to identify the best appraoch for multiple view-models communication mechanism (eg: View-Model A & View Model B are loosely coupled one. Now I want to pass one value to my View Model B from A. I don't want to use EvenAggregator and the models are independent).

The Event Aggregator is one of the option available however i am trying to avoid that usage for normal communication because of the security (due to its Global behaviour).

I used a controller in my Application and can easily route the data between two view-models. Is the controller in MVVM & Prism 4.0 a good approach?

If not, then can some one suggest or direct me to the better approach?

Comment: Out of curiosity: how are events a security threat? They are not different from method calls, or do you have an alternative for those as well?

Comment: I mean the EventAggregator which normally publish and need to subscribe in the other viewmodel however it publish at the global level i.e any module can access the data so I am looking for an approach without the EventAggregator for the VM to VM communication (within the same module). –

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you configure your controller to be loosely coupled without using the EventAggregator?

Comment: please suggest the approaches